# Stop outgoing SMS in Android without using operator barring or blocking

Tags: sms, sms-blocking

I want to block any outgoing SMS from my phone so that I cannot send SMS to anyone without using operator barring or blocking. I also want incoming messages to still work, but not outgoing.

Is there any way I can do that by an app, or hard coding, or ADB commands, or anything of sorts?

Comment: You should [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/239207/edit) your post to include manufacturer/model/OS version of your device. Also include if you allow for rooting and/or custom ROM.

Comment: type *\*#\*#4636#\*#\** in dialer, select SIM slot, save some invalid SMSC number (used for outgoing messages)